Can window glass be replaced with acrylic glass of the same dimensions?
In my place, all comercially available windows of are made of glass. But I read that windows can also be made from acrylic glass. I prefer this option because it is less prone to breaking.
Is acrylic glass a "perfect substitute" to glass? That is, given a window with one or two plates of glass, is it possible to simply take out the glass plates and put in acrylic glass plates of the exact same dimensions (width, height and thickness)?
If it is possible, does it require special expertise? Or can I simply find a window maker and tell him "make this window for me, but use acrylic glass instead of glass"?
CLARIFICATION: I know that there are differences between glass and acrylic glass. I meant "perfect substitute" in a technical sense. Can the window-maker simply put, instead of each glass plate in the glazing, an  acrylic glass plate of the same dimensions? (I am particularly interested in double-glazing windows).

Is there acrylic glass? thought acrylic was a type of plastic.

@SolarMike it is one of the names given to a plastic that is as transparent as a glass. Other names are: Perspex, Plexiglass, etc. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(methyl_methacrylate)

You can use it, but being a  "perfect substitute" will be up to you.  Glass and acrylic both have their pros and cons, so one will be more perfect some times.  I prefer using a table saw with a diamond blade to cut acrylic.

acrylic scratches easily ... it also builds up an electrostatic charge that attracts dust

Seems to be a matter of opinion without more specifics as to what you're trying to accomplish.

@SolarMike Acrylic glass? On the day that the lady asked me if I wanted "plastic silverware" with my take-out order, I officially gave up on being a stickler for terminology. We can't win. (But admittedly, acrylic glazing would have been less cringeworthy.)

As mentioned, acrylic plastic scratches easily and attracts dust electrostatically. It also might not meet local code for flammability, or for emergency egress (far stronger polycarbonate had to be removed from a building at which I worked because it could not be easily broken in case of fire). That  said, acrylic does have uses as a window -- but be aware of limitations.

@gnicko I meant "perfect substitute" in a technical sense. Can the window simply put, instead of any glass plate, an  acrylic glass plate of the same dimensions?

Also, I don't believe you can get insulated acrylic...

What kind of windows do you have?
Are these old-fashioned wooden frames with glass panes held by nails and grout?
Or a modern PVC manufactured frames?
For the first option, you can just ask window maker to cut you acrylic panes to size. Construction shops may carry them as well. You can install them yourself or ask a window maker to do so. Since its plastic, it can be cut to size if they don't fit perfectly.
For the second option, you will be dealing with "integrated windows" - those have two or more panes connected with separators and filled with gas of lower thermal conductivity. They can be ordered in any size, but best if you get PVC window installer to come and measure them for you. If distance is a problem, the panes can be removed from inside and you can carefully drive them to shop, if they are not too large.
Additional option - if they don't carry acrylic version, and you are fine with window being shatter-safe on just one side, you can order replacement panes with safety glass - those have layers of plastic foil inside the front glass pane, intended to prevent splinters from dropping. The glass still shatters, but stays whole, like car windshields do. There is also the 'bulletproof' version of this to prevent thievery and people breaking in, but requires modified window frames or they can just crowbar the window open.
A final note - take care to not confuse acrylic with polycarbonate. The other one is several times more expensive (but also very tough).

You can use acrylic/plexiglass instead of window glass.
I have done it often for windows in a barn, mainly for your reason of safety if they broke.
If breaking is the only worry/reason, there might be clear thin window plastic/film that can be placed on the window glass, like phone screen protectors.  It would keep the glass pieces together instead falling all over the place.
Modern windows usually are better at keeping heat in a home, that you would not be able to match with plexiglass windows.

Thanks! What is the term for the "window plastic that can be placed on the window glass"?

@ErelSegal-Halevi   Not quite sure of the right term.  I do know of window films to reflect the suns heat and some that reduces what you can see through windows from outside.  They basically just stick to the glass.  A local window store will know.  Window films in search should get you you started.

If existent windows need protection against breaking (from outside impacts), an alternative to exchanging the glass would be to add an acrylic glass sheet.
Feel free to add points.
Advantages:

Less work
Old windows' caulking may contain asbestos, often only to be removed by abrasive methods
Also the white paint on many old wooden frames contains lead, which is less likely to be set free via grinding/sanding old caulking
Much better insulation via additional air layer and acrylic glass (better insulation compared to normal glass)
Could be made quickly removable/replaceable via magnets, screwed frame parts etc.
Better "freedom" to expand at different temperatures (acrylic glass has a higher expansion/shrinking rate)
Better noise shielding (just replacing normal glass could reduce the noise filtering)
?

Disadvantages:

Reduces level of incoming light
Could produce more fogging (could be avoided/reduced by adding some cat litter into the new air layer)
More electrostatic attraction of dust (could be reduced/avoided by applying a very thin layer of dish washing fluid, polished on both surfaces. Those fluids contain ions that avoid local charges.)
Higher weight for the window frame mechanics
More optical disturbance by flexing/bending in windy hours
?

Compare the "storm windows", which are meant for extra insulation during winter, but are mounted from inside.

It is not a "perfect substitute." I think you will find that manufactured glass windows are cheaper.  If you are making home-made windows that dont actually open ít is probábly easier to buy sheets of plexiglass and somehow put them in.
